# Resizing UITextView automatically

Tags: objective-c, resize, uitextview

I'm a beginner in iOS development, and I have trouble resizing automatically a UITextView.

I created a Master-Detail Application. On my DetailViewController.xib I added a ScrollView that encompass a Label for the title, an image and under this image, a TextView in order to put a description that the user posted.
The problem is that the description depends on what my WebService returns, so I need it to be resized automatically.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    ...
    self.detailDescriptionTextView.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"adDescription"];

    CGRect frame = self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.detailDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
    self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame = frame;
)
```

The problem is that the TextView gets the content correctly but it doesn't resize at all.. I looked for an answer for a while and most of answers are what I tried...

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I realized something. In order to put some elements under the description, I've put a very small TextView for the description in the Interface Builder, is it a problem? If it is, how could I put other elements under this TextView, because there would be no more space on the Interface Builder no?

EDIT 2 : I finally succeeded. It seems like the problem was that I created the TextView by Interface Builder. By creating it programmatically, it worked perfectly. Here's my code if it can help someone:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 195, 280, 10)];
textView.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"adDescription"];
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hevlatica" size:14];
[self.scrollView addSubview:textView];
CGRect descriptionFrame = textView.frame;
descriptionFrame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = descriptionFrame;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First calculate the content height using

```
NSString *content = @"Hello how are you.";
CGSize size = [content sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourWidth, MAX_HEIGHT)
                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

and then set the frame of textView

```
[self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 30, 100, size.height + 10)];
```

Or

Add the content to your textview and then try this

```
CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
self.textView.frame = frame;
```

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answering so fast, but unfortunately it doesn't work :-(
In the first solution, I tried to replace the NSString *content by NSString *content = [self.detailDescriptionTextView.text]; and tried to use 200 (for yourWidth) and 999 (for MAX_HEIGHT) it doesn't change anything.

The second solution is exactly the same as I did if I understood what you meant :S

Comment: Are self.detailDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height & self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame.size.height the same ?

Comment: I tried this :
    NSLog(@"contentSize: %f", self.detailDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height);
    NSLog(@"frame: %f", self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame.size.height);

The first log returns 178.000000 and the second 178.000000 too

Comment: Hmm .... Have inserted the content (text) to your textview before doing this ? .. try logging textView.text also !!!

Comment: Yeah I inserted it before getting the size of the frame :-/
I updated my post at the end, maybe this could help?

Comment: Ohh .. tat is the issue ... you have to addSubView the textView for getting the correct contentsize.height.Otherwise contentSize.height & textView.frame.size.height will be same.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry but as I said I'm a beginner in iOS so ... what do you mean by adding the textView as subview?

I tried this :
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailDescriptionTextView];
after setting the content, but it makes my app crash ^^"

Comment: Whats the crash log ... ? Also First add textview to view then set the content & then call the frame adjustment code.

Comment: The crash log : 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

My code:
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailDescriptionTextView];
    self.detailDescriptionTextView.text = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"adDescription"];
    CGRect frame = self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.detailDescriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
    self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame = frame;

Comment: hmm ... i think your constraints(auto layout) is causing the issue. Not with this code.

Comment: Do you have an other idea that could help me have a TextView for description and other items under this one?
EDIT : I didn't precise it, but the whole thing (title, description etc...) are in a ScrollView inside the main view.

Comment: @arun.s what if you want the height of the constrained size to be unlimited? So the textview should scale to an unlimited height?

Answer (score 1):

```
 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(690.0, 2000.0);
 int h=10;
 CGSize size_txt_overview1 = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"adDescription"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
frame.size.height = size_txt_overview1.height;
self.detailDescriptionTextView.frame = frame;
```